# Efficient way to perform matrix multiplication repeatedly

Tags: r, performance, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to do the matrix multiplication `S_g` for each i, and each g with i. This is what I have tried so far, but it takes a huge amount of time to complete. Is there a more computationally efficient method to do exactly the same thing?

The main thing to note from this formula is the `S_g` uses X_gamma and Y[,i] in matrix multiplication set-up. X_gamma is dependent on value `g`. Therefore, for each i, I have to perform `g` matrix multiplications.

Here is the logic:

- For each i, the computation needs to be done for each g. Then, for each g, X_gamma is selected as a subset of X. Here is how X_gamma is determined. Let's take g = 3. When we look at 'set[3,]', we have that column B is the only one with value != 0. Therefore, I select the column B in X, and that would be X_gamma.

My main problem is that IN REALITY, **`g = 13,000`**, and **`i = 700`**.

```
 library(foreach)
 library(doParallel) ## parallel backend for the foreach function
 registerDoParallel()

 T = 3
 c = 100

 X <- zoo(data.frame(A = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), B = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6), C = c(0.7,0.8,0.9)),
     order.by = seq(from = as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 3, by = "month")) 

 Y <- zoo(data.frame(Stock1 = rnorm(3,0,0.5), Stock2 = rnorm(3,0,0.5), Stock3 = rnorm(3,0,0.5)), 
    order.by = seq(from = as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 3, by = "month"))

 l <- rep(list(0:1),ncol(X))
 set = do.call(expand.grid, l)
 colnames(set) <- colnames(X)

 I = diag(T)


 denom <- foreach(i=1:ncol(Y)) %dopar% {    
    library(zoo)
    library(stats)
    library(Matrix)
    library(base)

    result = c()
    for(g in 1:nrow(set)) {
        X_gamma = X[,which(colnames(X) %in% colnames(set[which(set[g,] != 0)]))]
        S_g = Y[,i] %*% (I - (c/(1+c))*(X_gamma %*% solve(crossprod(X_gamma)) %*% t(X_gamma))) %*% Y[,i] 
        result[g] = ((1+c)^(-sum(set[g,])/2)) * ((S_g)^(-T/2))
    }
    sum(result) 
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added the libraries to the code. Is that why you downvoted my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote. May be your question was not clear in what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks Metrics. I am unable to post a reproducible example, unfortunately. I tried to clarify my question as much as I can..

Comment: I am not sure whether you can replicate these in `data.table`.

Comment: make the question reproducible and simplify it more to the point (and/or post the formulae + explanation of what you want to do instead of that unreadable mess)

Comment: @eddi I apologize, but I clearly stated in my question that it is somewhat hard for me to post a reproducible example. I will still try to post the formula/some kind of example to make it clearer. No need to be rude really

Comment: I don't know what's hard about making up a few tiny matrices. If you want others to spend effort to help you, you should first spend some yourself.

Comment: The answers are good. I would also say I've used the R profiler. It takes stack samples, and you can read those directly. (I don't care for the summarization tool.) The stack samples do not have line numbers for the calls, but with luck you can figure them out. Also, on readability, CS people have learned to make their code more readable. I've seen other code by people who code primarily in R, and they are doing beautiful stuff, but it's pretty opaque.

Comment: I have updated my post with an example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that you fell victim to one of the classic blunders: not preallocating the output vector `result`.  Appending one value at a time can be very inefficient for large vectors.

In your case, `result` doesn't need to be a vector: you can accumulate the results in a single value:

```
result = 0
for(g in 1:nrow(set)) {
    # snip
    result = result + ((1+c)^(-sum(set[g,])/2)) * ((S_g)^(-T/2))
}
result
```

But I think the most important performance improvement that you could make is to precompute expressions that are currently being computed repeatedly in the `foreach` loop.  You can do that with a separate `foreach` loop.  I also suggest using `solve` differently to avoid the second matrix multiplication:

```
X_gamma_list <- foreach(g=1:nrow(set)) %dopar% {
  X_gamma <- X[, which(set[g,] != 0)]
  I - (c/(1+c)) * (X_gamma %*% solve(crossprod(X_gamma), t(X_gamma)))
}
```

These computations are now performed only once, rather than once for each column of `Y`, which is 700 times less work in your case.

In a similar vein, it makes sense to factor out the expression `((1+c)^(-sum(set[g,])/2))`, as suggested by tim riffe, as well as `-T / 2` while we're at it:

```
a <- (1+c) ^ (-rowSums(set) / 2)
nT2 <- -T / 2
```

To iterate over the columns of the `zoo` object `Y`, I suggest using the `isplitCols` function from the `itertools` package.  Make sure you load `itertools` at the top of your script:

```
library(itertools)
```

`isplitCols` let's you send only the columns that are needed for each task, rather than sending the entire object to all workers.  The only trick is that you need to remove the `dim` attribute from the resulting `zoo` objects for your code to work, since `isplitCols` uses `drop=TRUE`.

Finally, here's the main `foreach` loop:

```
denom <- foreach(Yi=isplitCols(Y, chunkSize=1), .packages='zoo') %dopar% {
  dim(Yi) <- NULL  # isplitCols uses drop=FALSE
  result <- 0
  for(g in seq_along(X_gamma_list)) {
    S_g <- Yi %*% X_gamma_list[[g]] %*% Yi
    result <- result + a[g] * S_g ^ nT2
  }
  result
}
```

Note that I **would not** perform the inner loop in parallel.  That would only make sense if there weren't enough columns in `Y` to keep all of your processors busy.  Parallelizing the inner loop could result in tasks that are too short, effectively *unchunking* the computation and making the code run much slower.  It's much more important to perform the inner loop efficiently since `g` is large.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I have updated my post with an example. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mariam Fixed a serious bug in handling of X_gamma_list.  See the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last part doesn't work. The index `g` in `result` makes no sense here. Should I compute `sum(set[g,])` externally as well?

Comment: Awesome. Running it now. Thank you for your prompt answer, very helpful :)

Comment: Final question: would the `foreach(Yi = Y)` take each column from matrix Y?

Comment: @Mariam Yes, that is exactly what it does.  It can avoid sending the entire `Y` to each of the workers depending on the parallel backend.

Comment: Again, very helpful. Thanks a lot! The only thing I don't like about this parallel computing is that it slows down my computer a lot..

Comment: Since my `g` is very large, I have modified the `for` loop to be a `foreach` loop. Now I have two nested `foreach` loops, with indices 1:700 and 1:13000 respectively. It's taking more than half-day to complete... I am not sure there is a better/faster way to implement this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37186/discussion-between-steve-weston-and-mariam)

Answer (score 2):

I second @eddi that you should give some objects so we can run code. The following remarks are based on staring:

1) you could save `S_g` in a preallocated vector and do that last line ( `((1+c)^(-sum(set[g,])/2)) * ((S_g)^(-T/2))` ) out of the loop, since `rowSums(set)` will give you what you need. That removes one instance of indexing with `g`

2) indexing is slowing you down. Don't use `which()`. Logical vectors work just fine.

3) `-T/2` is dangerous. It can mean `-0.5`. If that's what you want, then just do `1/sqrt(S_g_vec)` for speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try to come up with an example, and I will edit my post.

Comment: The `doParallel` package compiles the body of the foreach loop, so it doesn't need to be turned into a function.

Comment: An interesting thing that I learned is that indexing zoo objects (such as `X`) doesn't work properly with logical vectors, which is why my example still uses `which`.  But your point is well taken.